# How to solve the NullPointer exception in android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

This is a simple app in android. It shows `nullpointerexception` while executing. 
I can't get the value from the `edittext`. Here I just want to get the value from the `edittext`.
But it shows `nullpointerexception`..

how to solve this?

```
public class Calci extends Activity  {
    Button add;
    String str1;
    String str2;
    EditText txt1;
    EditText txt2;
    TextView tv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calci);

        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        txt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        str1=txt1.getText().toString();
        txt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        str2=txt2.getText().toString();
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        addition();

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                addition(); 
            }
        });
    }


    private void addition(){
        int res=0;
        res=Integer.parseInt(str1)+Integer.parseInt(str2);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calci, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Find the line which is giving you the error from logcat.

Comment: It didn't show the logcat. A message box is displayed, running the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you are setting  default values for  `editText1` and `editText2` in xml or if you want to access values enter by user then chnage your code as and remove addition() before setOnClickListener  :

```
      //  addition();  comment this line 
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                  str1=txt1.getText().toString();
                  str2=txt2.getText().toString();
                  addition(); 

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove  `addition();` from `onCreate()`. As I have doubt when its first time called your `EditTexts` are empty.

Also when you call `addition()` method you have to get the text from your both `EditTexts`.

And your method `addition()` something like,

```
 private void addition()
 {

  int res=0;
  str1=txt1.getText().toString();
  str2=txt2.getText().toString();
  res=Integer.parseInt(str1)+Integer.parseInt(str2);
  tv.setText(String.valueOf(res));
 }
```

Comment: Then where i should declare the method??

Comment: Only in Button's `onClick()`. Either If you want to put in your `onCreate()` then put some default values in EditText's attributes in Layout XML files. before calling `additon()` Or give some default values to `str1`and `str2`.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the additiion() method in your oncreate() and change the method as like below

```
private void addition()
  {
         str1= str1==null?"0":str1;// do like this, so that if str1 returns null then it will be replaced by 0
         str2= str2==null?"0":str2;
         int res=0;
         res=Integer.parseInt(str1)+Integer.parseInt(str2);
         tv.setText(String.valueOf(res));
  }
```

Comment: when ever your string going to be null then it will automatically help you by getting nullpointer exception by using this code

Answer (score 0):

You do not call addition() this method here  :

```
        str2=txt2.getText().toString();
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        //addition();


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```